# How to append element to jquery return value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append a javascript created button to the return value of this function which locates the toolbar of a reportviewer on an aspx page:

```
var findtoolbar = function () {
    var $all = $('table div');
        for (var i = 0, len = $all.length; i < len; i++) {
            if ($($all[i]).css('background-image').toLowerCase().indexOf('toolbar_bk.png') != -1)
                return $($all[i]);
        }
    return null;
}
```

Then I try to add the button to the toolbar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var retval = findtoolbar;
    (retval).append($print);
});
```

But this throws an error (of course?) saying append is not supported.

The whole idea is to implement a cross browser print solution for MS reportiewer (which only works on IE8 or less since it depends on Active X).

Comment: You are not calling `findtoolbar`. Change `var retval = findtoolbar;` to `var retval = findtoolbar();`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I mistakenly supposed that since findtoolbar was a var, it should be call without parentheses, for I know functions should be called with parentheses. I now understand that even though declared as a var, findtoolbar is still a function. Héhé, lesson learned, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Can simplify this and let jQuery manage the loops by using `filter()`

```
    var findtoolbar = function () {
        return $('table div').filter(function(){
            return $(this).css('background-image').toLowerCase().indexOf('toolbar_bk.png') != -1;
         });        
    }


   findtoolbar().append($print);
```